# Irish Grid 100km Shapefile

Tags: vector-grid, ireland

Does anyone know where I can get a shapefile (or similar) for the 100km Irish grid?

I cannot seem to find one anywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_grid_reference_system. Ordnance Survey Ireland also has a page explaining the grid, but no-where to access it that I can find.

Comment: try https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/ireland-shapefile

Comment: Good thought - and useful, thanks. I should have specified though, I was hoping for something that covers both the Irish Republic and Northern Ireland (both of which are on the Irish Grid).

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you can create one using the `Vector->Research Tools->Create Grid` tool.

Setting some reasonable values for the [Irish Grid](https://epsg.io/29903) Extent

[image]

Produces an plausible looking grid

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a go at this